# AJAX loading in HTML to a div not working

Tags: ajax, jquery

Hi I'm trying to dynamically insert a html file into a div on my page. I have tried the jQuery .load and .get as well as a longer AJAX method that I know of. None have worked so far.

To complicate matters I am using onhashchange for AJAX deep linking. My code looks like this:

```
function locationHashChanged() {
    if (location.hash === "#link1") {
         var path = "link1.html";
         $('#content').load(path); 

         return false;
    }
}

window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;




<a href="#link1">Link1</a>
```

This then should insert the link1.html into #content div when link1 is clicked. The hash change is fine because when I put alerts in it is fine. However the inserting of the HTML is where it fails. Any ideas why and how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: your code looks good, please check that you have added jquey.js http://jsfiddle.net/PQMLU/

Comment: yes, using the most up to date jquery and am hosting it.

Comment: any error in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared my cache then looked at the Console again and JavaScript was not loading properly so I deleted the .min.js file and downloaded it again and hey presto it works. The code was fine :)

Delete this question as it doesn't have that much use?

Comment: I think you don't need to delete it.  So someone will need this info :)

Comment: Fair enough :) it can stay